# How do I set up Logitech's LED Illumination SDK with Java?

Tags: java, logitech-led-illumination-sdk

When a make a simple test program with Logitech's LED SDK and run it, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError with the message:

```
C:\Users\cwa38\AppData\Local\Temp\LogitechLedJNI.dll4587977834410494064: Can't find dependent libraries
```

What I have done so far:

1. I downloaded the SDK from https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/developer-lab.html
2. I extracted it
3. I made a new Java project in NetBeans
4. I added the logiled.jar file to my new project as a dependency
5. I made a new class and copied the simple test program from the documentation (code is below)
6. I clicked "run" and got the UnsatisfiedLinkError described above

I see that the SDK download comes with some .dll files and a .lib file, but I have no idea what to do with these files.  The included documentation makes absolutely no mention of them.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```java
import com.logitech.gaming.LogiLED;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogiLED.LogiLedInit();
        LogiLED.LogiLedSetLighting(100, 0, 0);
        LogiLED.LogiLedShutdown();
    }
}
```

And here is the full documentation from Logitech (yes, it really is this short):

> The following steps show how to make the Logitech SDK work with a Java program.  Please adapt the steps to your game for things to work.
>
> Steps
>
> 1. Copy the SDK’s Lib\logiled.jar to your project’s directory.
> 2. Configure your project’s Java Build Path to include the logiled.jar.
> 3. Call the functions from the JNI wrapper in your Java code as follows:
>
> ```
>     import com.logitech.gaming.LogiLED;
>
>     LogiLED.LogiLedInit();
>     LogiLED.LogiLedSetLighting(red,blue,green);
>     LogiLED.LogiLedShutdown();
> ```
>
> 4. Compile and run your program.

The full stack trace for the error I get is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\cwa38\AppData\Local\Temp\LogitechLedJNI.dll4587977834410494064: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:384)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:228)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:170)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2389)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at com.logitech.gaming.LogiLED.<clinit>(LogiLED.java:205)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:20)
C:\Users\cwa38\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.4\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\cwa38\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.4\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: you should put those dll and lib files into same location with that jar, if you create a github repo with reproducer it will be easier to solve this.

Comment: @özkanpakdil Thank you for the response.  I tried putting the dll and lib files in the same folder as the jar, but still got the same error message.  [Here](https://github.com/Chickencharm/KeyColors) is the project directory I am left with when I follow the exact steps described in my question.

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132922/175554 I do not think you can install 32 bit anymore but worth to check, another approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/67369117/175554 you may have some wrong dll. and last but not least do you have some virus scanner, that may affect jvm, try to disable and test.

Comment: The native library (DLL) name and location is different for LGS and GHub.  This might be a problem.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have been using GHub so far.  I will try using LGS and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your project in my netbeans but failed with

```
 project com.cwa380:KeyColors:jar:1.0: logitech:gaming:jar:9.00 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

then I created a new project from ant, as long as you are using this logitech jar which is not really in maven repository, you dont need to have maven project.

[image: netbeans create ant project]

then I added the logiled.jar as image below
[image: project properties->libraries]

good news when I run the code I get no exception. output below

[image: execute output at the bottom]

and when I try to use code completion netbeans lists the functions nicely.

[image: logiled functions]

here are my versions of tools

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4
Java: 17; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17+35-2724
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 17+35-2724
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\ozkan\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.4
Cache directory: C:\Users\ozkan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.4
```

in github I found https://github.com/larsgrefer/logi-led you may contact with Lars(@larsgrefer), looks like he knows how to use logitech SDK.

here is my project https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/JavaApplication1 make sure you have added logiled jar in correct path to libraries

Comment: I followed these exact steps and still ended up with the exact same UnsatisfiedLinkError described in the question.  The Netbeans peoject I was left with is [here](https://github.com/Chickencharm/KeyColorsAnt).

Comment: probably we are not using same versions then, I added jdk netbeans version to my answer.

Comment: I have been using Netbeans 12.4 with JDK 16 on Windows 10.  I just updated to JDK 17, so we are now using the exact same setup, and I still get the error.

Comment: I added my netbeans project in a repo, if you are still getting UnsatisfiedLinkError, means you did not have logiled jar in correct path, can you update your question and add full stack trace ?

Comment: I just downloaded your repo and ran it, I still get the error.  I put the full stack trace in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> 4. I added the logiled.jar file to my new project as a dependency

Need to add x64 version, not x86.

\Lib\JNI\x64\logiled.jar

should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).